# Change Image when Browser Window is Resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slideshow on my home page that uses images in a landscape orientation. However, when the browser is resized, the images eventually get clipped. To prevent this, I want to swap the landscape-oriented images to square ones when the browser reaches a certain pixel width. But it must switch back when expanded again. How would I go about this?

Comment: Are the images in image tags, or set as background images?

Comment: Use a `.resize()` handler that checks the size and changes the image if necessary. Or use a media query in your CSS.

Comment: @phynam; they are in image tags.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides this [resize event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/), And you can use it like,

```
$(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
      var width = $(window).width();
      var height = $(window).height();

      $('yourimage').attr('src', toAnotherSource);
      // or you can do anything with the image here.
   });
});
```

Comment: So, where do I state the browser width to be reached before the image will be changed? And does this code also change it back once the browser is expanded? Is it too much to ask of you to create a jsfiddle of this in practice?

Comment: @TCorin There you have the `width` and `height`, just wrap the function to change your image inside an `if` condition. Yes, you can change it back when the browser is expanded. Yes, it's too much or you can just provide your fiddle in your question.